# Como retrasar la respuesta de una peticion o hacerlo correctamente con una verificacion en angular 8?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, http, promesas, angular8

Lo que sucede es que tengo una api rest en nodejs realmente sencilla con las operaciones básicas y lo que ocurre o he podido ver es que el post se ejecuta y seguidamente el get en angular, pero no se lista reactivamente. Esto llamo mi atención y lo que sucedió es que si doy click en agregar otra vez entonces si se lista, mi sospecha es que no esta dándole el tiempo suficiente y lo trata como si no existiera.

```
listgenre(){
    this._GenreService.getGenrer()
      .subscribe
      (
        data=>
        {
          this.lstGenres=data;
          console.log(data);
        }
      );
    }
  addGenres(){
    this._GenreService.createGenrer(this.addGenre)
      .subscribe
      (
        data=>
        {
          this.listgenre();
        }
      )

  }
```

**El método listgenre() es el que lista al iniciar la aplicación.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al segundo intento recién me listo ambos datos.

Comment: Saludos reverti la edición de tu pregunta pues la respuesta no debe ir en tu misma duda, para ello justo debajo dispones de la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Use lo siguiente pero dudo que sea una buena alternativa.

```
 private delay(ms: number)
     {
       return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
     }

     private async sleep()
     {
       await this.delay(1000);
     }





 addGenres(){
    this._GenreService.createGenrer(this.addGenre)
      .subscribe
      (
        data=>
        {
          this.sleep().then(() => this.listgenre());

        }
      )

  }
```